# how to change multiple image src using jquery in django

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates

i'm trying to change the image src for each comment depending on the first letter found in the users name

```
{% for comment in articles.comments.all %}
      <div class="comments py-2 my-3">
           <div class="comments-img-wrapper">
                <img src="" class="comment-image" alt="">
           </div>
           <div class="comments-details">
                 <h5 class="comment-user-name">{{comment.user}} <span class="float-right date">{{comment.created}}</span></h5>
                 <p>{{comment.body}}</p>
            </div>
       </div>
       {% empty %}
       <p>there are no comments</p>
{% endfor %}
```

and the jquery code i'm using is this

```
<script>
    $(".comment-image").each(function(){
        username = $('.comment-user-name').text();
        usernameFirstletter = username.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        console.log(usernameFirstletter)
        $(".comment-image").attr('src', '/static/img/avatars/' + usernameFirstletter + '.svg');
      });
</script>
```

but for some reason it keeps repeating the image of the first ccomment for the remaining comments, can anyone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$('.comment-user-name').text()` to get the username which always returns text content first among the collection independent of the current `img` tag within the callback.

So you need to get `.comment-user-name` related to the current `img` tag, for that get common parent(`.comments`) and get it.  In addition to that, you have to update `src` attribute of the current element instead of `$(".comment-image").attr(...)` which updates attribute of all elements.

```
<script>
    $(".comment-image").each(function(){
        let username = $(this).closest('.comments').find('.comment-user-name').text();
        let usernameFirstletter = username.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        console.log(usernameFirstletter)
        $(this).attr('src', '/static/img/avatars/' + usernameFirstletter + '.svg');
      });
</script>
```

---

You can make it even simpler by using [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method with a callback which iterates over elements internally and updates with the returned value of callback.

```
<script>
    $(".comment-image").attr('src', function(){
        let username = $(this).closest('.comments').find('.comment-user-name').text();
        let usernameFirstletter = username.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        return '/static/img/avatars/' + usernameFirstletter + '.svg';
      });
</script>
```